# Requirement is transfer of files between s3 buckets through lambda, taking keys of source s3 file dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

```
import boto3
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    message = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    print(message)
    old_bucket_name = 'audio'
    old_prefix = '2020/06/10/17/'
    new_bucket_name = 'dev'
    new_prefix = 'source_metadata/'
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    old_bucket = s3.Bucket(old_bucket_name)
    new_bucket = s3.Bucket(new_bucket_name)
for obj in old_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=old_prefix):
    old_source = { 'Bucket': old_bucket_name,
               'Key': obj.key}
# replace the prefix
    new_key = new_prefix + obj.key[len(old_prefix):]
    new_obj = new_bucket.Object(new_key)
    new_obj.copy(old_source)
```

I get the path and file name that i place in s3 in variable "message", how can i define as prefix of my destination bucket (dev)

Comment: Why are you triggering this as a Lambda function? What is sending the `Key` to the function? Is it an Amazon S3 event, when a new object is created?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes s3 event triggers the lambda

Comment: 2020/06/10/17/test.txt  output of print(message). I want to take this output and use it for destination bucket key

Comment: If one object is triggering the Lambda function, why are you wanting to loop through multiple files to copy? Can you describe (in words, not code), what you are actually wanting to achieve? For example, what triggers the function, and what should the function do?

Comment: We get files in s3 in folders 2020/06/16/  or 2020/06/17 etc it can be one or many files,, as soon as the files arrive, s3 event triggers the lambda and lambda should place all the files in destination bucket (dev/source_metadata/)

Comment: Are you wanting to retain the source path, eg copy from `2020/06/16/foo.txt` to `source_metadata/2020/06/16/foo.txt` or to `source_metadata/foo.txt`?

Comment: @John Rotenstein Copy to source_metadata/foo.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A separate Lambda function will be triggered for each object that is created.

Therefore, the Lambda function should only move the object that triggered the function.

Here is some code that will move the object:

```py
import boto3
import urllib

TARGET_BUCKET = 'dev'
TARGET_PATH = 'source_metadata/'

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get incoming bucket and key
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    source_key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])

    # Extract filename without path
    filename = ('/' + source_key).rsplit('/', 1)[1]

    # Copy object to different bucket
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    copy_source = {
        'Bucket': source_bucket,
        'Key': source_key
    }
    s3_resource.Bucket(TARGET_BUCKET).Object(TARGET_PATH + filename).copy(copy_source)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot John Rotenstein..Worked like charm!!