# Trying to do a prefix matching in s3 BOTO3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to do a prefix matching of a file uploaded or a file that exists.

For example, if there is a file that is called `random_123` then go look for a folder with the name `random` in a different s3 bucket and retrieve all the files based on the count.

The partition key would be `_` (underscore).

For example: If I upload a file named `Random_dataset` inside one bucket, look for a subsequent folder in a different s3 bucket named `Random` that already has a few files inside (based on the count of the files).

Below is the code I've written so far. Need assistance on how I could proceed further.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
empty_list=[""]
i=0
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket-name')
count_obj=0
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='folder-name/'):
    print(obj.key)
    empty_list.append(str(obj.key))
    i=i+1
    count_obj = count_obj + 1
print(count_obj)
print(empt_list)
```

Comment: What specific part is causing you difficulty? It would appear that you are wanting to write an AWS Lambda function, so the function should start by extracting the Bucket and Key of the object that 'triggered' the Lambda function. The code should then presumably use that `Key` as the basis for the `Prefix` that you wish to count. See the first few lines of this example code: [Requirement is transfer of files between s3 buckets through lambda, taking keys of source s3 file dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62407236/174777)

Comment: FYI there are quite a few problems with this code, unrelated to your main issue. The variable `i` is unnecessary. The variable `count_obj` is unnecessary (just use `len(empty_list)`). The name `empty_List` seems to be a poor choice of name. You should initialize `empty_list` to `[]` instead of `[""]`. Object keys are strings so your `str(obj.key)` conversion to string is unnecessary.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein in the last line of the code ' s3_resource.Bucket(TARGET_BUCKET).Object(TARGET_PATH + filename).copy(copy_source)' instead of copy_source can I use something like like get_source? Is get method available for s3? I want to get the objects and pass it to a sagemaker processing job function.

Comment: How do you intend to pass the data to SageMaker? Do you simply want the contents of the object to pass (eg as a string), or will you pass it as a file, or perhaps as a reference to the object in S3? What function call will you be making? And what has this got to do with "the count of the files"?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein through the same lambda function. The file that triggered the lambda function would be the input file 1 of the processing job and the second input file would be picked up from the other folder. Now the count of files will determine the number of sagemaker processing jobs to be created. So,for example the other folder has 3 files then, the sagemaker will have to start 3 jobs one after the other (create_sagemaker_job would run inside a for loop). This is sort of like parallel processing but not really parallel processing.

Comment: **It seems your requirement is:** When an object is created in Bucket A, S3 will trigger the AWS Lambda function. The function will retrieve the name of the object that was created, and will extract the portion of the filename before the underline for use as a folder name. The function will then look in Bucket B, with `Prefix` equal to that folder name. It will loop through each of the objects in that Prefix, starting a SageMaker job for each object and passing the contents of the object as input to the SageMaker job. Does that seem accurate?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein PRECISELY! You've perfectly summed up my requirement .Now i'm an amateur programmer with minimal python knowledge which is why I'm taking of help of forums like stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your requirement is:

- When an object is created in Bucket A, S3 will trigger the AWS Lambda function.
- The function will retrieve the name of the object that was created, and will extract the portion of the filename before the underline for use as a folder name.
- The function will then look in Bucket B, with Prefix equal to that folder name. It will loop through each of the objects in that Prefix, starting a SageMaker job for each object and passing the contents of the object as input to the SageMaker job.

Here is some example code to get you started.

```py
import boto3
import urllib

TARGET_BUCKET = 'other_bucket'

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    target_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(TARGET_BUCKET)

    # Loop through each event record (Can be multiple records passed-in)
    for record in event['Records']:
        
        # Get details of the object that triggered the event
        source_bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        source_key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key'])
        
        # Extract name of target prefix from Source Key (eg 'random_123' becomes 'random/')
        target_prefix = source_key.split('_')[0] + '/'
        
        # Loop through contents of Target Prefix within Target Bucket
        for object in target_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=target_prefix):
    
            # Call your SageMaker stuff here
            print('Object key:', object.key)
            print('Object contents:', object.get()['Body'].read())
```